# How to save green dao db file in internal storage?

Tags: android, database, local-storage, database-backups, android-internal-storage

I am using Greendao database for locally storing the data base, now I need to store the daily database backup  in the internal storage too. How  can i achieve this?

Comment: Where is it now? And where does it get back upped already? And to where in internal storage exactly do you want your backup?

Comment: I want to  make a folder in storage and to add a daily back of db in it so even if the app data  is reset  or app is uninstalled its data remains saved in the phone.

Comment: Is the database stored in a file? I think so. If so then just copy that file.

Comment: `now I need to store the daily database backup in the internal storage too` Well... I read here that there is a database and a database backup already. So it looks that you want to make yet another backup. I asked you about that before...

Comment: I would think that you would make a daily database backup only.

Comment: Yes I want to make a daily data base back up.. so in case if the app is reset or uninstalled the data base back up remains there in phone. How can I acheive  this?

Comment: You did not answer most of my questions so i cannot help you now.